# Preventing server (Git/ssh) access during LVM snapshot

Tags: backup, git, lvm

If a Git operation is ongoing at the time of an LVM snapshot, the repository can (and will) be snapshoted in a corrupt state. (This has been discussed a lot http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1ax0oa/how_kdes_1500_git_repositories_almost_were_lost/ )

The question is how to solve this correctly. Git access is via git-shell via ssh (with keys) to a linux machine. Stopping access for something like 20 min each night is not a problem for our department, but I'm afraid the devil is in the details.

What what I came up with so far makes me feel I'm reinventing some wheel I'm not aware of. from a cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 0.
# poll during 20 min for ongoing git usage to stop
countdown=$((60*20))
while pgrep -u git >/dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
    countdown=$((countdown-1))
    if [ $countdown -eq 0 ] ; then 
       break
    fi
done

#1
#disable login to the git user by setting the shell to /bin/nologin
chsh -s /bin/nologin git

#2
# 
# wait again for up to 20 min for all processes to complete 
# (we *may* have just missed it between step 1 and 2)
#
countdown=$((60*20))
while pgrep -u git >/dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
    countdown=$((countdown-1))
    if [ $countdown -eq 0 ] ; then 
       break
    fi
done

#3
# kill too slow git sessions (This is actually safe)
if pgrep -u git >/dev/null ; then
    killall -u git 
    sleep 30 
fi
if pgrep -u git >/dev/null ; then
    killall -9 -u git 
    sleep 10
fi
if pgrep -u git >/dev/null ; then
    echo Failed to kill stale git $(pgrep -u git)
fi

#4
# make the lvm snapshot ...

#5
# change back the shell
chsh -s /usr/bin/git-shell git
```

I'm keen to learn if there are more standard solutions, or if my solution is flawed.

Something about the approach feels too hand-hacked. I also don't like to think about corner cases like defunct processes. Also the server may go down during the script, so I would have to set back the shell to git-shell to repair that (either via cron or at boot).

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way is to use a more appropriate backup strategy. Why would you use LVM snapshots, when you can just backup using git itself?

Simle, untested example

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /backups/git
for repo in $(ssh repo_host ls /srv/git); do
    if [ ! -e $repo ]; then
        git clone --mirror repo_host:/srv/git/$repo
    else
        (cd $repo; git fetch origin)
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1 for good point. git clone mirror is a compliment and will also be done. Here I'm considering lvm snapshots as that's already a part of the infrastructure. mirrors are good for restoring git usage-errors. A full backup (including hooks, configurations, and what not) is good for restoring a server.

Comment: Good point. Though for that you could use rsync to sync anything but *HEAD, refs and objects.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a standardized solution for this and your approach looks reasonable to me.  A few caveats:

1. I'd take it a step further and block all non-root logins, as you really don't want users logging in and doing things with your storage while your LVM operations run. Fortunately this is pretty simple with `/etc/nologin`, provided that your PAM config in `/etc/pam.d` is including `pam_nologin.so`. Many distros do but you'll want to test. `man pam_nologin` for details.
2. Use `pkill` instead of a pgrep+killall. It uses the same process matching and return code logic as pgrep.
3. You're redirecting STDOUT but not STDERR. One trick I use is enclosing blocks of commands to be redirected in `{}` brackets, and redirecting the output of the brackets. Just remember that these brackets require a return or `;` after the last command if you're doing a one-liner.

---

Example of #3:

```
{
    echo foo
    echo bar >&2 # output bar to STDERR
} >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: +1. Thanks you, those are useful comments. The reason I don't redirect stderr is that errors are in this case really errors and I have no real reason for hiding them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you block any ssh logins for the period?
add to sshd_config:

`#DenyGroups <a supplementary group for all git users>`

then in the beginning of your backup cronjob:

```
sed -i -e 's/^#DenyGroups/DenyGroups/' sshd_config
kill -HUP /var/run/sshd.pid
```

and reverse when done. For the users currently logged in though, I know no other options but kill their sessions similar to what you do already. Or wait until they logout.

Comment: Why is this better? I'm not sure I'd like to touch the sshd configuration for the machine in a cron job. setting the shell also seems a bit too much, but at least I use the tool for the job (chsh) there. Thinking about it, I guess I could tamper with the git-users .ssh/ to prevent login instead of the passwd file.

Comment: for the starters it will be much more graceful than killing running git processes which can eventually lead to a non consistent backup. i also dont see any problem with modifying sshd configuration as far as you know what you are doing. whenever better or not, up to you. i just share my experience with providing merge windows.

Comment: The task of killing ongoing git activity and preventing new ones to start are independent in both our solutions. Eventually we have to kill ongoing git activity to be sure to have a clean backup. I wait up to 20 min for any git activity to complete. Anyway, thank you for your input.